# How to correctly calculate speed in gradient fill animation and rotation

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I have a view with layers: dashed semi-circle, circle that moves around semi-circle, and gradient fill mask on my dashed semi-circle. I can't correctly calculate animations duration in both animations. Currently my circle moves faster than the gradient in the semi-circle fills.

Here's my code:

```
class DashedCircleView: UIView {

    var circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    var circleGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    var movingCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createDashedSemiCircle()
        fillDashedSemiCircleWithGradient()
        createMovingCircle()
        animateGradient()
        rotateMovingCircle()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        createDashedSemiCircle()
        fillDashedSemiCircleWithGradient()
        createMovingCircle()
        animateGradient()
        rotateMovingCircle()
    }

private extension DashedCircleView {

    func createDashedSemiCircle() {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).cgPath
        circleLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
        circleLayer.masksToBounds = false
        circleLayer.strokeColor =  UIColor.darkGray.cgColor //border of circle
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor //inside the circle
        circleLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        circleLayer.lineDashPattern = [10, 10]
        layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)

        circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2),
        radius: min(frame.size.height, frame.size.width) / 2,
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: .pi,
        clockwise: false).cgPath
    }

    func createMovingCircle() {

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0,
                          y: 0,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20)
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        movingCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        movingCircleLayer.path = path.cgPath
        movingCircleLayer.bounds = rect
        layer.addSublayer(movingCircleLayer)
    }

    func rotateMovingCircle() {

        var affineTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0.0)
        affineTransform = affineTransform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi))

        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: frame.size.height / 2),
        radius: min(frame.size.height, frame.size.width) / 2,
        startAngle: .pi,
        endAngle: 3 * .pi / 2,
        clockwise: true).cgPath

        let orbitRotateAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        orbitRotateAnimation.path = circlePath
        orbitRotateAnimation.duration = 4
        orbitRotateAnimation.isAdditive = true
        orbitRotateAnimation.repeatCount = 0
        orbitRotateAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationLinear
        orbitRotateAnimation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto
        orbitRotateAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        orbitRotateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        movingCircleLayer.add(orbitRotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }

    func fillDashedSemiCircleWithGradient() {
        layer.addSublayer(circleGradientLayer)
        circleGradientLayer.mask = circleLayer
        circleGradientLayer.frame = CGRect.init(origin: self.bounds.origin, size: self.frame.size)
        circleGradientLayer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circleGradientLayer.borderWidth = 1
        circleGradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        circleGradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5) // horizontal gradient
        circleGradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.0] //max 0.88
        circleGradientLayer.bounds = bounds
        circleGradientLayer.colors = [
            #colorLiteral(red: 0.9372549057, green: 0.3490196168, blue: 0.1921568662, alpha: 1).cgColor,
            UIColor.init(red: 211/255, green: 211/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        ]
    }

    func animateGradient() {

        _ = 7
        let endValue: Double = 23
        let curValue: Double = 12
        let toValue = (curValue * 0.88) / endValue

        let colorsAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CAGradientLayer.locations))
        colorsAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards
        colorsAnimation.fromValue = [0.0, 0.0]
        colorsAnimation.toValue = [toValue, toValue]
        colorsAnimation.duration = 4.2
        colorsAnimation.repeatCount = 0
        colorsAnimation.autoreverses = false
        colorsAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
        circleGradientLayer.add(colorsAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}

extension Double {
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

At first, the gradient does not move, and then it accelerates sharply, and in the middle it slows down.

Comment: It's not that the gradient *"accelerates and slows down"* ... the problem is that the first "10-pt dash" is almost vertical and the last "10-pt dash" is almost horizontal. If you comment-out this line: `//circleGradientLayer.mask = circleLayer` you'll see it clearly. I think, to get the effect you want, you'll need to rotate the gradient layer at the same speed as the blue circle. A bit tricky to get the mask to "stay put" while rotating the gradient layer underneath... you might need to use a couple of views layered on top of each other.

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution to this?

Comment: @DonMag no, how to close the topic?

Comment: As a general rule... If you have solved your question, it's courteous to other users to post your solution as an answer to your own question. If you realize it was due to a mistake, go ahead and delete it. If you've "given up and moved on" you can just leave it be... someone may come across it in the future and have a solution (which would benefit other users).

Answer (score 0):

Two issues...

First, it's not impossible, but it is difficult to sync two different types of animations.

Second, the gradient acceleration / deceleration you see are not due to actual change in animation speed, but due to the fact that the dashed-curve you're trying to fill is not linear.

One possible solution is to overlay a couple of subviews...

- view with blue "dot" layer on top
- view with gradient layer underneath
- rotate the layers in sync

We can't mask the gradient layer (with the dashed-semi-circle) directly, though, because if we do then the dashed-circle will rotate with the gradient. Instead, we can mask the "gradient view" with a "dashed-circle view".

Here's how it ends up:

[image]

Here's how it looks animated - the top goes to 45-degrees, the middle goes to 90-degrees and the bottom one rotates to 180-degrees (actual duration was set to 2-seconds... viewing these gifs will appear different).

Using the dashed-semi-circle as a subview:

[image]

Using the tased-semi-circle to mask the gradient view:

[image]

And here's the code used:

```
class DashCircleViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let dCircle1: MyDashedCircleView = {
        let v = MyDashedCircleView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.clipsToBounds = false
        return v
    }()

    let dCircle2: MyDashedCircleView = {
        let v = MyDashedCircleView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.clipsToBounds = false
        return v
    }()

    let dCircle3: MyDashedCircleView = {
        let v = MyDashedCircleView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.clipsToBounds = false
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        view.addSubview(dCircle1)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dCircle1.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            dCircle1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 50.0),
            dCircle1.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            dCircle1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dCircle1.widthAnchor),
        ])

        view.addSubview(dCircle2)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dCircle2.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            dCircle2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dCircle1.bottomAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            dCircle2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dCircle1.widthAnchor),
            dCircle2.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dCircle2.widthAnchor),
        ])

        view.addSubview(dCircle3)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dCircle3.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),
            dCircle3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dCircle2.bottomAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            dCircle3.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dCircle1.widthAnchor),
            dCircle3.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dCircle2.widthAnchor),
        ])

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    var isReady: Bool = false

    @objc func didTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        // when view is tapped, toggle dCircle views between
        // initial state and animated
        isReady.toggle()
        if isReady {
            // animate circle1 only 45 degrees (25% of 180 degrees)
            dCircle1.doAnim(duration: 2.0, rotationDistance: 0.25)
            // animate circle2 only 90 degrees (50% of 180 degrees)
            dCircle2.doAnim(duration: 2.0, rotationDistance: 0.50)
            // animate circle3 180 degrees (100% of 180 degrees)
            dCircle3.doAnim(duration: 2.0, rotationDistance: 1.00)
        } else {
            dCircle1.resetAnim()
            dCircle2.resetAnim()
            dCircle3.resetAnim()
        }
    }
}

class MyDashedCircleView: UIView {

    // holds the blue dot layer
    var movingCircleView = UIView()

    // the blue "dot"
    var movingCircleLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    // will use gradientLayer and will be masked by circleMaskView
    var gradientView = UIView()

    // gradient layer
    var gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    // uses circleLayer and will use be used to mask gradientView
    var circleMaskView = UIView()

    // the dashed semi-circle layer
    var circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        gradientView.backgroundColor = .clear
        gradientView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        circleMaskView.backgroundColor = .clear
        circleMaskView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        movingCircleView.backgroundColor = .clear
        movingCircleView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // add gradientView as subview
        addSubview(gradientView)

        // add moving circle view
        addSubview(movingCircleView)

        // constrain subviews to self
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            gradientView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            gradientView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            gradientView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            gradientView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),

            movingCircleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            movingCircleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            movingCircleView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            movingCircleView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        ])

    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // create the gradient layer
        createGradientLayer()
        // add it to gradient view
        gradientView.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)

        // create semi-circle layer
        createDashedSemiCircleLayer()
        // add it to circle mask view
        circleMaskView.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)

        // during dev only
        // set to true to show dashed-circle as a subview instead of masking the gradient view
        if false {
            insertSubview(circleMaskView, belowSubview: movingCircleView)
            // constrain circleMaskView to self
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                circleMaskView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                circleMaskView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                circleMaskView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
                circleMaskView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            ])
        } else {
            // apply the mask
            gradientView.mask = circleMaskView
        }

        // create blue dot layer
        createMovingCircleLayer()
        // add it to movingCircleView
        movingCircleView.layer.addSublayer(movingCircleLayer)

    }
    func resetAnim() -> Void {
        // reset to starting conditions (without built-in animations)
        movingCircleLayer.removeAllAnimations()
        gradientLayer.removeAllAnimations()
    }
    func doAnim(duration _duration: CFTimeInterval, rotationDistance: CGFloat) -> Void {
        // perform the animation
        animateBoth(_duration, rotationDistance: rotationDistance)
    }
}

private extension MyDashedCircleView {

    func createDashedSemiCircleLayer() {
        circleLayer.lineWidth = 2.0
        circleLayer.strokeColor =  UIColor.darkGray.cgColor //border of circle
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor //inside the circle
        circleLayer.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
        circleLayer.lineDashPattern = [10, 10]

        // inset by 2-pts so we don't clip the edges of the dashed-circle-line
        let f = bounds.insetBy(dx: 2, dy: 2)

        circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: f.midX, y: f.midY),
                                        radius: min(f.maxX, f.maxY) / 2,
                                        startAngle: 0,
                                        endAngle: .pi,
                                        clockwise: false).cgPath
    }

    func createMovingCircleLayer() {

        // inset by 1-pt to sit centered on the dashed semi-circle
        movingCircleLayer.frame = bounds.insetBy(dx: 1.0, dy: 1.0)
        let rect = CGRect(x: -10.0,
                          y: bounds.midY - 10.0,
                          width: 20,
                          height: 20)
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
        movingCircleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        movingCircleLayer.path = path.cgPath

    }

    func createGradientLayer() -> Void {
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
        gradientLayer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        gradientLayer.borderWidth = 1
        // vertical gradient - top will be gray, bottom will be orange
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        // produces half-orange half-gray with no "fade gradient"
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.colors = [
            UIColor.init(red: 211/255, green: 211/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
            UIColor.init(red: 211/255, green: 211/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
            UIColor.init(red: 239/255, green: 89/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
            UIColor.init(red: 239/255, green: 89/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor,
        ]
    }

    func animateBoth(_ duration: CFTimeInterval, rotationDistance: CGFloat) {

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(duration)

        //-- animate blue dot layer rotation

        let circleOrbitRotateAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        circleOrbitRotateAnimation.values = [0, .pi * rotationDistance]
        circleOrbitRotateAnimation.isAdditive = true
        circleOrbitRotateAnimation.repeatCount = 0
        circleOrbitRotateAnimation.calculationMode = .linear // kCAAnimationLinear
        circleOrbitRotateAnimation.rotationMode = .rotateAuto // kCAAnimationRotateAuto
        circleOrbitRotateAnimation.fillMode = .forwards // kCAFillModeForwards
        circleOrbitRotateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        movingCircleLayer.add(circleOrbitRotateAnimation, forKey: nil)

        //-- animate gradient layer rotation

        let gradientRotateAnimation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        gradientRotateAnimation.values = [0, .pi * rotationDistance]
        gradientRotateAnimation.isAdditive = true
        gradientRotateAnimation.repeatCount = 0
        gradientRotateAnimation.calculationMode = .linear // kCAAnimationLinear
        gradientRotateAnimation.rotationMode = .rotateAuto // kCAAnimationRotateAuto
        gradientRotateAnimation.fillMode = .forwards // kCAFillModeForwards
        gradientRotateAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

        gradientLayer.add(gradientRotateAnimation, forKey: nil)

        //--

        CATransaction.commit()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll dive into your code asap. And i've found another solution! 1 static dashed circle at level 0, then in 1 and 2 levels - not dashed circle with dashed circle as a mask, and blue sphere at level 3. Then i animate both blue and not dashed circle with "stroke start" with 2.0 secs